# icon is not displayed with fontAwsome

Tags: html, font-awesome, angular7

I have the following code on my html page with angular 7.x and fontAwesome version 5.7.1

```
<i class = "fa fa-pencil"> </ i>
```

All the other icons and buttons are displayed well showing trash can and others but the pencil does not show it? what can happen?

Comment: Are you using a PRO version of Font Awesome? Anyway, here's the Font Awesome site that shows the code for pencil [Font Awesome v5 pencil](https://fontawesome.com/icons/pencil-alt?style=solid)

Comment: no, i´m not using the PRO version!

Comment: Ok, well you could use what they are showing on the site `<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
```

This icon name replaced version 4 "fa-pencil".

here you can find more help: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4